# How to implement jQuery on top of existing Mootools site

Tags: jquery, namespaces, mootools

I have taken over the development of a site, which is 50% complete.

The previous developer has been using Mootools for a few functions thus far, I am far more proficient in jquery (i.e. have no knowledge of Mootools), and so wish to include the jquery library and use jquery from here on in.

Can anyone offer any links, guidelines or advice regarding this situation?

**EDIT:** I cannot remove the mootools functions completely, they need to coexist.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169164/should-i-convert-from-mootools-to-jquery

Comment: I would recommend converting to jQuery completely, especially if it's only a few functions.  No matter what library you're coming from or going to, best to narrow it to one if there's very little code in one library that can be done in the other, less payload, less complication, less JS for the client to run.

Comment: No I cannot remove the Mootools functions, they need to coexist.

Comment: @KJF that is a different question actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the only conflict that may arise is the use of $ by both libs.
Both jquery and mootools have a no-conflict setting, which helps to get around this problem.
See [mootools' Dollar Safe Mode](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/) and [JQuery's noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Technically you only need one of the two solutions and using JQuery's noConflict() has the advantage that JQuery itself is already better isolated. Mootools extends many Natives and defines many global functions that other plugins may depend on.

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) is the JQuery document that explains how to use noConfict().